# Create headers from csv file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-template, modern-document-library

I want to use a csv file to create headers in a document library or some other file type if that works better.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new document library or just you want to add columns to your existing document library?

Comment: @Ganesh Both new and used would be nice but the immediate need is new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, you will always need to create the columns manually and specify the column type or use some third party tools. You can do it in PowerShell, however still you need to specify each column settings.

Comment: Thank you Jerry. After a lot of head to wall I am convinced that you are correct. Still having you confirm it is really helpful in removing the spot of doubt in the back of my brain.